# Get substring of input from one point until end of line in c

Tags: c, substring

First of all, I'm working on a program in C that based on the input of the user it returns different things. I have this function that given a line a separator and an index it goes through the line and divides the string into substrings depending on the separator and returns the substring according to the index:

```
void get_substring(char line[], char result[], char separator, int index){
   int i, j=0, my_index=0;
   for(i=0; line[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if(line[i]==separator)
           my_index++;
        else if(my_index == index)
           result[j++]=line[i];
    }
    result[j]='\0';
}
```

So basically I write on the console **/pmsg user Hello I'm John** and I use the function get_substring() to save the **user** in a global variable char a_result2[] and the entire **input line** is saved in a global variable named a_message[]. The output of the function **/pmsg** should be:

```
**output : private message (user): Hello I'm John**
```

The problem is I don't know how to retrieve the entire message, because the message could be composed of a lot of words, and with my function get_substring I can only get the substring if I know the length of the message. I would appreciate it very much if you could help me, thanks. Here is the code for the function pmsg that I have already:

```
void pmsg(){

  printf("output : private message (%s): ", a_result2);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your compiled binary is called e.g. `pmsg` and you want to call it with arguments you have to use quotes around the message

```
./pmsg username "Hello I'm John"
```

and then use main's arguments. Here is an example:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int i;      
    printf("output : private message (%s) : %s\n", argv[1], argv[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

Here `argv[1]` is the username and `argv[2]` is the whole message.
Check how to use arguments with main [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.htmlhttp://) and [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_command_line_arguments.htm)